# Open camera in android using Camera Api

Tags: android, camera

I have tried all the existing methods out there.. but everytime the application force closes. Here is the code. Please help me debugging it.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.camera1;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView; 
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private Camera cameraObject;

 private ShowCamera showCamera;  

 private ImageView pic; 

 public static Camera isCameraAvailiable(){

     Camera object = null; 

     try {  object = Camera.open(); 

     }       catch (Exception e){        

     }       return object;   

 }  

 private PictureCallback capturedIt = new PictureCallback() {  
      @Override      
      public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {  
      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data .length);       
      if(bitmap==null){        
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
          }       
      else{
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();           
          }     
      cameraObject.release(); 
      } 

     };




    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    cameraObject = isCameraAvailiable(); 
    showCamera = new ShowCamera(this, cameraObject);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(showCamera);   

    } 

    public void snapIt(View view){   
    cameraObject.takePicture(null, null, capturedIt);   
    } 


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

ShowCamera.java

```
package com.example.camera1;

import java.io.IOException;  
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder; 
import android.view.SurfaceView; 


public class ShowCamera extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder holdMe; 
 private Camera theCamera;
 public ShowCamera(Context context,Camera camera) {
    super(context);
     theCamera = camera;
     holdMe = getHolder();     
     holdMe.addCallback(this);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      try   {         
          theCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
          theCamera.startPreview();
          } catch (IOException e)
          {     

          }   

}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

} 


 }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="199dp" >

    </FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_capture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:onClick = "snapIt"
    android:text="@string/Capture"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

I am making this for android gingerbread and above versions. where my target sdk is Android Kitkat.
While testing the app on gingerbread it opens the application but simply shows a white screen that is it doesnt load the layout and force closes.. please help..!!

Comment: When an app force closes, it puts the exception into the "logcat" window in eclipse. You need to look at that.

Comment: remember once camera app crashed it may not release the cam properly so even if your code is correct in next turn it won't still work until your camera is properly released

Comment: override the onCreate method of your mainactivity

Answer (score 0):

To open the camera,use the following code appropriately:

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
  Camera.CameraInfo info=new Camera.CameraInfo();

  for (int i=0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
    Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);

    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
      camera=Camera.open(i);
    }
  }
}

if (camera == null) {
  camera=Camera.open();
}
```

Add the SurfaceView to a FrameLayout in order to display it.

Instead of returning the Camera,you could instead use the global Camera instance variable.The camera is released in onPause like this:

```
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera=null;
   //remove SurfaceView from the FrameLayout you added it to
```

You can retain the Camera.Parameters object and use it to set the parameters to the value by placing a check in your surfaceChanged.

You could also consider starting your Camera in a seperate Thread in onCreate as it has been done here:

```
    //This code is from AOSP ICS:
      Thread mCameraOpenThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          try {
              mCameraDevice = Util.openCamera(Camera.this, mCameraId);
           } catch (CameraHardwareException e) {
             mOpenCameraFail = true;
          } catch (CameraDisabledException e) {
            mCameraDisabled = true;
        }
    }
});
```

This is the onCreate method:

```
   super.onCreate(icicle);
   mCameraOpenThread.start();
   SurfaceView preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    SurfaceHolder holder = preview.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    // Make sure camera device is opened.
    try {
          mCameraOpenThread.join();
          mCameraOpenThread = null;
        } 
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
     //ignore
    }
```

The link to the code is here http://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera/+/ics-factoryrom-2-release/src/com/android/camera/Camera.java